# How to RC test an installer but ship with a different user manual

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I have a product bootstrapper built using Wix in VS2012. Works fine, but our RC testing process is hampered by the usual late delivery of the user manual. The installer can only be built once the user manual arrives and hence the RC testing is delayed. So I wonder if there is a solution that will give us an installer for functional testing and some way to add the user manual without rebuilding that installer. The final installer must be a single file bootstrapper.

I'm think of a solution like building an MSI, without the user manual, and use that for most of the functional testing. When the user manual arrives take that MSI (without rebuilding) and create a bootstrapper that adds the user manual. That way I'm thinking we only need some smoke testing and installer testing to be able to ship.

Seems silly to have to wait for a user manual to start testing but we need the certainty of a tested MSI and simple bootstrapper build process so that MSI testing remains valid.

Also ... only one install must show in the user's installed programs list.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this on CDROM media where the payload for the bootstrapper package was uncompressed.  CM just dropped the latest manual file on top and CM'd it.  Sounds like you can't do this due to the single file requirement.

I've worked on large projects where functionality was changing up to the last minute and the doco writers needed the latest version to doco .... it's a viscious cycle and not silly at all.

There's no one technical solution.  Maybe you just make the doco a 2nd deliverable.